# Failed to post an array to server using AFNetworking

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I use AFNetworking to post an array comprising the contact details in the device to the server. Given below is my code.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"UserContacts": contactsArray};//contactsArray is NSMutableArray
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:baseUrl parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE : %@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {    
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

The response I got back is

> RESPONSE : "failed"
>       **Notice**:  Undefined index: UserContacts in **C:\xampp\htdocs\creator\php\controller\contactsync.php** on line **101**

The php code is given below

```
public function insertios(){

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['UserContacts'])){

        echo json_encode('failed');
        $contact = $_REQUEST['UserContacts'];
        echo $contact;

    }else{

        echo json_encode('Success');

    }
}
```

Please tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`php://input`** read-only stream to access post data instead of **`$_REQUEST`** like this

```
<?php 
    $postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

After that you can decode your post data depending content-type.

You have used **NSDictionary** for binding data which is treated as json string at PHP server so you have to read request data via php input stream wrapper.